# List processes with the most CPU time.(Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I make it that no system services are enumerated? I would like to have both the system process as well as all other system services such as svchost not in the list.

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -first 3 | Format-Table CPU,ProcessName,Id -hidetableheader
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the other answer, but here's another possibility that doesn't need admin rights, although it might not be fool proof:

Most system services run within a process named `svchost` so you could simply exclude these processes with `Where-Object`:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.name -ne 'svchost'} | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -first 3 | Format-Table CPU,ProcessName,Id -hidetableheader
```

Comment: On my computer (Win10, PowerShell 5) this only shows "chrome" and "conhost" so i'm not sure this is correctly identifying non-system processes.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case, i've just tested it on Win 10 PS5.1 with a non-admin console and get 3 processes (and if I remove the `select-object` get all processes that are not svchost (which is generally a lot more than 3).

Comment: Oh, never mind it was my mistake, i had somehow managed to select the console after running the command so the console was waiting for me to finish selecting before it showed all the processes. Very nice code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be in Admin mode.

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"} | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -first 3 | Format-Table CPU,ProcessName,Id -hidetableheader
```

Is this what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answers for their simplicity, however you can use the WMI class `Win32_Process` to retrieve a list of process and the method `.GetOwner()` to get the owner of the process.

As system processes do not show an owner we can easily filter on process that **do** have an owner, showing *most* non-system processes (I say most because svchost shows up under my account every now and then).

```
# Get all processes
$processes = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Process

foreach($process in $processes)
{
    try
    {
        $processOwner = $process.GetOwner()
    }
    catch
    {
        continue
    }

    if ($processOwner.User -ne $null)
    {
        $processData = Get-Process -Id $process.ProcessId

        $process | Select-Object -Property @{n='CPU';e={$processData.CPU}},Name,ID | Sort-Object -Property CPU
    }
}
```

Comment: The behavior of Windows processes amazes me again and again.